# Internet noticeably slower on one computer while faster on another connected to the same router

Tags: networking, router, internet, modem, internet-speed

I have a 120Mb/s Internet connection and it works well on my laptop with 1Gb/s network card and Windows 7. But it works too slow on another computer which is older and which have 100Mb/s network card and also Windows 7. Both computers are connected via wired Ethernet.

I realize that I won’t get the full 120Mb/s on a 100Mb/s network card, but as far as I know it should work with speed about 90Mb/s, but it is only getting about 35 Mb/s.

I am using [Ubee EVW3226 modem/router device](http://www.ubeeinteractive.com/products/cable/evw3226) and I have updated network card drivers on the systems in question.

Comment: coyld try a live OS like bart pe or a linux one

Comment: @JakeGould Yes, both are connected via wired Ethernet. I'll add this info to my question.

Comment: @barlop I'll try that soon, but right now I can't.

Comment: Some ethernet adapters have trouble actually moving data as fast as they claim to - though this was more of a problem with 1 Gbit adapters (lighting the Gb light, but not being able to fill the link) than 100 Mbit adapters, as far as I recall.

Answer (score 1):

Few things to try (test your speed after each step to see if the problem persists):

- Connect the computer to the router using a different ethernet cable.
- If you have a switch in between the computer and the router, try connecting the computer directly to the router.
- Check link speed/duplex:

  1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open the Run menu, and type `devmgmt.msc` to open Device Manager
  2. Expand Network adapters and double-click the appropriate adapter
  3. Navigate to the Advanced tab
  4. Select Link Speed & Duplex from the Property list and make sure its value is set to Auto Negotiation.

[image]

- Reset the TCP/IP stack<sup>**1**</sup>:

  1. Click Start, search for `cmd`
  2. Right-click cmd.exe and click Run as administrator
  3. Type `netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt` and hit Enter
  4. Reboot the computer.

<sup>**1**</sup>You can also use the Fix it wizard from the following link:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/299357

A corruct TCP/IP stack can cause several issues with the network connection. Resetting the TCP/IP stack will overwrite the following registry keys:

```
SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters 
SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DHCP\Parameters
```

This has the same effect as removing and reinstalling TCP/IP (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/299357).

If none of the above solves the problem, your network adapter may be bad, or you could have some sort of malware which is hogging the bandwidth.

Comment: This would be better if you explain a little (doesn't have to be an essay) about what resetting the TCP/IP stack does. Generally speaking, don't encourage people to do things blindly, especially when the implications are non-obvious (I've been using IBM compatibles since the late 1980s, and I don't know what resetting the TCP/IP stack on Windows will do); explain *why* you believe that particular step is relevant to solving the problem described by the OP, and say something about what the potential pitfalls might be.

Answer (score 0):

I have two Windows 10 PCs, both with wire connection to the same router. One was giving me 5Mbps downloads and the other 60Mbps. Tried rebooting and resetting TCP/IP as described here. No help. Then I found a suggestion to reboot to Safe Mode with Networking to try to determine if the problem was hardware related. In Safe Mode with Networking all was fine (60Mbps on the “slow” computer too). Rebooted normally and all remained fine.

No idea what was going on, but problem resolved.